# Write docx file from string using apache poi

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have this code for making docx file from string `message`

```
                XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();
                XWPFParagraph tmpParagraph = document.createParagraph();
                XWPFRun tmprun = tmpParagraph.createRun();
                tmprun.setText(message);
                fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("tes.docx"));
                document.write(fos);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(tampilan.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(tampilan.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } finally {
                try {
                    fos.close();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(tampilan.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
```

That string contains some text extracted from a word document. But this puts the whole text under one paragraph.
This is string that I want to write

> Bahan /           : Antrum
>
> Keterangan        : GERD
>
> Diagnosis Klinik  : NERD+ antral gasitris superfisial Gr. 1
>
> Pemeriksaan PA    : Blok Parafin
>
> Makroskopik   : Diterima satu biji jaringan kecil ukuran kurang lebih 0,01 cc penampang putih, padat, lunak.

Thanks for help.

Comment: If you want to make an "enter", you should use `addBreak()`, in your case `tmprun.addBreak()`

Comment: Not only "enter", but I want formating like before extracted from a word document.